# WPF communication between multiple ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm currently working with a WPF application and has several problems. So far I've been putting all the business logic in a single ViewModel and what I noticed now is that ViewModel doesn't have a particular context.

An example would be:

```
        <telerik:RadSplitContainer Orientation="Vertical" telerik:DockingPanel.InitialSize="750,200">
            <telerik:RadPaneGroup IsContentPreserved="False" telerik:ProportionalStackPanel.RelativeSize="200,300" >
                <telerik:RadPane 
                        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CategoryTemplate}"  
                                    Content="{Binding CategoryViewModel}" />
                </telerik:RadPane>
            </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
            <telerik:RadPaneGroup IsContentPreserved="False" telerik:ProportionalStackPanel.RelativeSize="100,120">
                <telerik:RadPane Header="Items list" 
                                 CanUserClose="False" CanUserPin="False"
                                 CanDockInDocumentHost="True">
                    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ItemsListTemplate}"  
                                    Content="{Binding ItemsViewModel}" />
                </telerik:RadPane>
            </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
        </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
```

However, this is how the mainwindows.xaml look like, which is built up by multiple views which is specified as a datatemplate. At this moment I decided to extract the business logic from the huge common viewmodel and create a ViewModel for each View.

I have two views, one for category and one for items corresponding to the category. These two views contain a gridview which show the categorys in CategoryView and Items corresponding to the category.

The viewmodel which contains all the items is at initial empty, and the category just retrieves all existing categories from DB. I also have a SelectedCategory in CategoryViewModel which contain the grid row item I choose.

The thing I want to do is at a selection of a row in the grid in categoryView, I want the CategoryViewModel to tell the ItemsViewModel to retrieve its items corresponding to the categoryID I'm retrieving from CategoryViewModel. Then refresh the itemscollection in the itemsViewModel with INotifyPropertychanged and refresh the view on the grid.

My mainView view and viewmodel:

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.InitializeCommands();
        this.ItemsViewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
        this.CategoryViewModel = new CategoryViewModel();

    }

    public ViewModelBase CategoryViewModel
    {
        get { return this._categoryViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (this._categoryViewModel != value)
            {
                this._categoryViewModel = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public ViewModelBase ItemsViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._itemsViewModel == null)
            {
                this._itemsViewModel;
            }
            return this._itemsViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._itemsViewModel != value)
            {
                this._itemsViewModel = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

An example of another view datatemplate which is used in MainView:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NewsTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   <telerik:RadBusyIndicator x:Name="BusyIndicator">
            <telerik:RadGridView Name="gridView"
                                                 ItemsSource="{Binding 
         Category}"
                                                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay}">   
                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding={Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>     
            </telerik:RadGridView>
        </telerik:RadBusyIndicator>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>`
```

Added viewmodel for items:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Item> GetItems
    {
        get
        {
            this._getItems = GetFromDb.GetItems(CategoryID)

            return this._getItems;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._getItems != value)
            {
                this._getItems = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("GetItems");
            }
        }
    }

    public QueryableCollectionView Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this._items = new QueryableCollectionView(GetItems(CategoryID));
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._items != value)
            {
                this._items = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(() => Items);
            }
        }
    }
```

MainViewModel (if you look over I got a method GetFromDb.GetItems(CategoryID) which retrieves the items):

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.InitializeCommands();          
        this.CategoryViewModel = new CategoryViewModel();
        this.ItemsViewModel = new ItemsViewModel();

        this.CategoryViewModel.OnChanged += (s, e) => {

            //this one?
            this.ItemsViewModel.ContractMetaDatas(CategoryViewModel.ID)
            //this one?
            this.ItemsViewModel.ContractMetaDatas = new QueryableCollectionView(GetFromDb.GetItems(CategoryID));
        };
    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using 1 view model per page?

Comment: Hi @Stefan. Yes I'm using a viewmodel per view / page or rather component.
I got a grid 1000x1000 which I have splitted into several regions containing different views / view resources. It's a onepage application with many views on the same page.

Comment: Ok; assuming you have these viewmodel in some sort of container: define an event in the CategoryViewModel that the categoryID  has changed (you can use the INotifyPropertyChanged's event for this but it is not ideal). Capture this in your container an pass it through to the ItemsViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The thing I want to do is at a selection of a row in the grid in categoryView, I want the CategoryViewModel to tell the ItemsViewModel to retrieve its items corresponding to the categoryID I'm retrieving from CategoryViewModel. Then refresh the itemscollection in the itemsViewModel with INotifyPropertychanged and refresh the view on the grid.
>
> How can I achieve this?

Well, basically you can use a typical setup with events:

Fire an event from your `CategoryViewModel` and handle it in the overall container.

```
 public class MainViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
     public CategoryViewModel CategoryViewModel {get;set;}
     public ItemsViewModel ItemsViewModel {get;set;}

     public MainViewModel()
     {   
         this.InitializeCommands();
         this.ItemsViewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
         this.CategoryViewModel = new CategoryViewModel();
         //wire up the event 
         this.CategoryViewModel.OnChanged += (s,e) => {
            //perform update here
            this.ItemsViewModel.UpdateWithId(this.CategoryViewModel.SelectedId);
        };
     }

    ///...
 }
```

The category:

```
public class CategoryViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //fire this when appropiate
    public event EventHandler OnChanged;
    ///...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I would like to test your method but I'm having a couple question.
//Perform update here , what logic would be inserted there? and what about the   public YourMainViewModel(){}, would this be the constructor?

Could you give me a realistic example when you actually update the ItemsViewModel upon change of SelectedCategory gets a value / changes?

Comment: Updated it a bit: `perform update` means: update your data there. `public `YourMainViewModel(){}` is indeed a constructor, I altered it to your definition. I think this would be a realistic example based on the info you have given. I can get into more details but that would require more insights in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Do you know if your method works with async?
By using private CategoryViewModel _categoryViewModel; the content doesn't recognize the view model, but by setting it to viewmodelbase, it works. Can I just use the view model base?

        `private CategoryViewModel _categoryViewModel;
        private ViewModelBase _categoryViewModel;
                        
<ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CategoryTemplate}"  
          Content="{Binding CategoryViewModel}" />`

Comment: Yes, you can do it like that; i hav made them public... the most important thing is the event. Define it and handle it. It shouln't impact the rest of your code.

Comment: Hello, I've also updated the code in the thread. 
How does my ItemViewModel recieve the ID sent for MainViewmodel?

Comment: Set the `CategoryID` variable and reload the collection.

Comment: Would it work with how I set up as described over? Since it doesn't take any parameter?

Comment: `public ObservableCollection<Item> GetItems
    {
        get
        {
            this._getItems = GetFromDb.GetItems(CategoryID)

            return this._getItems;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._getItems != value)
            {
                this._getItems = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("GetItems");
            }
        }
    }`

How does this one get the param from MainViewModel?

Comment: It takes `CategoryID` as parameter; make sure you set it in `//perform update here` section or rewite that part.

Comment: Hi, I've updated once more. If you refresh and check my new code, that is my version of your method. Does it look correct?

Comment: Hmm, that's a hard one because that depends on your specific code. I think you should test it and conclude that if it runs as expected it's "good enough" ;-)

Comment: Do you invoke the event somewhere?

Comment: How do I do that? :)

Comment: Hahaha.... I would be faster to just post all your code ;-) .... any how: in the `CategoryViewModel`, you need to fire (or invoke) the event. Put it where it makes sense: it's when the category is changed, I beleive something like this: `OnChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());`

Comment: Could I ask what new EventArgs does? :)

Comment: Of course; but I will advise you to follow some tutorials about programming. I must say; congrats that you have come this far. Anyhow: EventArgs, are event arguments, part of the typical event/subscriber pattern. Normally you pass some parameters through it, e.g.: OnMouseMove -> EventArgs can contain x and y coordinated. In your case it could contain the actual CategoryID. I left it out because the scope is to broad for this question.

Comment: Thanks! :) 
I've coded a lot more in C and Python when it comes to AI, so events and viewmodels is a bit new to me. Well, I managed to make it work. Thtanks a lot.

I also got another problem. 
I'm also doing the same for item with OnChangedSelectedItem, but what I notice is that whenever I go back to click on a category, it also invoke the event that I've sat in ItemsViewModel, which should invoke another ViewModel for example.

Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Try to wrap it up in a new question; you'll get a lot of extra attention ;-)

Comment: Do you mean creating a new question? :)

Comment: yes, it helps.. make sure you put in all the details but don't make it a burden to read.

Comment: @FredrikLinger: And dont forget to upvote the people that helped you ;-)

Comment: thanks for the help. I'm wondering can these OnChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());    be invoked in like viewmodel.commands.cs?

Comment: Should I create many events for a ViewModel or only a single one? Like different events in the ViewModel for different purposes. Like an OnSelectedCategory -> invoke this and do this. and OnUpdatedCategory event -> do this and this.

Comment: Yes, normal design is to create separate events for separate "happenings"

Comment: Ok, thanks! Do you know if it should work to invoke in Viewmodels.Commands?

Comment: Basically yes, this will work and under normal conditions it's valid if (and only if) the changing property is part of `Viewmodels.Commands` as well. If the property is not part of that class, I wouldn't invoke an event which indicates that a property outside it's boundaries has changed.

Comment: Thanks! Let's say if I got 2 events which has common actions but the only difference is that the second event also refresh the collection. Should I make two seperate events or just have one event and figure out when to refresh the collection given condition?

Comment: The event only indicates that something has happened. It's up to the underlying action to determine what to do. If this is based on a parameter, you can pass it as event argument.